# Meteor (v0.8.2) app stopped working on Windows machine

Tags: meteor, windows-8.1

I have been developing a meteor app on a Windows 8.1 machine until recently it wouldn't start when issuing the 'meteor' command.  Instead it fails with the following error:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Starting your app...
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\.meteor\tools\dc9fb5197a\lib\node_modules\fibers
\future.js:173
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\.meteo
r\packages\dev-bundle-fetcher\59dd6fad07\os\packages\dev-bundle-fetcher\dev-bund
le'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\.meteor\tools\dc9fb5197a\tools\packages.j
s:2090:23
```

The error is correct, (i.e. the referenced directory isn't there).  However, I don't know how/why that is now an issue.

This first happened when meteor was downloading v0.8.3 in the background while I was running a v0.8.1 app.

Any help on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I had this problem, can't remember how I fixed it though!  I think I got rid of the old meteor installation before installing the new one

Comment: How did you get rid of the old on?  Completely delete it and start over with just the app files? I tried that and I tried resetting as well. Still the same error keeps coming back.

Comment: I think I just deleted the directory from memory, then ran the .exe from https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Comment: Great idea. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Add it as an official answer so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the directory from disk, then run the installer from https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows